# Opening a PDF file and searching for names there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, search, pdf

I have a PDF file. And I want to search for names there.

1. How can I open the PDF and get all its text with Ruby?
2. Are there are any algorithms to find names?
3. What should I use as a search engine: Sphinx or something simpler (just LIKE sql queries)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tough question. These domains remain in the research area of semantic web. I can only suggest some tracks but would be curious to know your definite choice.

1. I'd use pdf-reader: https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader
2. You could use a Bloom Filter matching some dictionary. You'd assume that words not matching the dictionary are names... Not always realistic but it's a first approach.
   To get more names, you could check the words beginning with a capital letter (not great but we keep on finding some basic approaches). Some potential resource: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4235
3. For your search engine, the two main choices using Rails are Sphinx and SolR.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

To find proper names in unstructured text, the technical name for the problem you are trying to solve is [Named Entity Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_entity_recognition) or Named Entity Extraction. There are a number of different natural language toolkits and research papers which implement various algorithms to try to solve this problem. None of them will get perfect accuracy, but it may be good enough for your needs. I haven't tried it myself but the web page for [Stanford Named Entity Recognizer](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml) has a link for Ruby Bindings.